# Как убрать тряску блоков при наведении

Tags: css3, html5, codepen

Задавал стили для навигации столкнулся с тем что контент отпрыгивает при наведении. 
В чем может быть проблема?

https://codepen.io/VadimStrelov/pen/bPyxpv

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 58px;
  &__logo {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(../img/header_logo.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 137px;
    height: 28px;
  }
  &-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    &__item {
      margin-left: 20px;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 16px;
      letter-spacing: 0.8px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
    }
    &__item:hover {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #00E593;
      transition-duration: 3ms;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Drag</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-main">
    <header>
      <div class="header">
        <a href="#" class="header__logo"></a>
        <ul class="header-list">
          <li class="header-list__item">Home</li>
          <li class="header-list__item">About</li>
          <li class="header-list__item">Contents</li>
          <li class="header-list__item">Books</li>
          <li class="header-list__item">Education</li>
          <li class="header-list__item">Skills</li>
          <li class="header-list__item">Portfolio</li>
          <li class="header-list__item">Clients</li>
          <li class="header-list__item">Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="block-book">
        <div></div>
        <div class="block-text">
          <p class="block-text__name">- By Emma Anderson</p>
          <h1 class="block-text__title">BUKEE: THE BOOK<span>A room without books is like a body without a soul</span></h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis
            iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque.</p>
          <a href="#" class="block-text__btn">Buy this book - $15.00</a>
          <small>* Some conditions may applicable</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="block-author">
        <div class="block-text">
          <p class="block-text__name">- By Emma Anderson</p>
          <h2 class="block-text__title">Emma Anderson<span>A room without books is like a body without a soul</span></h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis
            iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque.</p>
          <a href="#" class="block-text__btn">Read full biography</a>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-counter">
        <p><span>12</span> Total published books</p>
        <p><span>5</span> Happy readers</p>
        <p><span>15,000</span> Happy readers</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page page-gray">
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2 class="page__title">Book Contents</h2>
      <p class="page__subtitle">Let’s see what we have covered in the book</p>
      <div class="block-about">
        <div>
          <h3>About the book</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna ali qua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ull amco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillu m dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
          <div>
            <p>Featured in:</p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Table of contents</h3>
          <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            <li>Consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
            <li>Labore et dolore magna</li>
            <li>Consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
            <li>Labore et dolore magna</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            <li>Consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
            <li>Labore et dolore magna</li>
            <li>Consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
            <li>Labore et dolore magna</li>
          </ol>
          <button>More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас у блока отступ 8px, при наведении добавляется 3px рамки, и того 11px становится.. Уменьшите отступ при наведении до 5px, чтобы с рамкой было 8px

```
&__item:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00E593;
    transition-duration: 3ms;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать:

box-sizing: border-box;

Тогда border будет частью высоты элемента, если такая задана. Еще, как вариант, можно использовать outline вместо border.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing